# REST Web API post related entities

Tags: asp.net-web-api, codefluent

Hi CodeFluent enthusiasts!

I have these two related entities in my model:

```
<cf:entity name="Main" defaultUsePersistenceDefaultValue="false" namespace="idscommerce" categoryPath="/idscommerce">
<cf:property name="Id" key="true" />
<cf:property name="Nom" />
<cf:property name="Ordre" />
<cf:property name="URL" />
<cf:property name="Icona" />
<cf:property name="Texts" typeName="{0}.MainTextCollection" relationPropertyName="Main" dataMember="true" />
```

```
  <cf:entity name="MainText" defaultUsePersistenceDefaultValue="false" namespace="idscommerce" categoryPath="/idscommerce">
<cf:property name="Id" key="true" />
<cf:property name="Text" />
<cf:property name="Idioma" typeName="{0}.Idioma" relationPropertyName="MainTexts" />
<cf:property name="Main" typeName="{0}.Main" relationPropertyName="Texts" />
```

In my API, GET is working right, but when I POST (I'm using the [FromBody]Main value option) it goes into a loop at LoadByMain method from MainTextCollection.

```
    // GET api/Main/id
    public Main Get(string id)
    {
        idscommerce.Main value = idscommerce.Main.LoadByEntityKey(id);
        if(value == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return value;
    }

    // POST api/Main
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Main value)
    {
        if(value == null || !value.Save())
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, value);
    }
```

What it's weird is that the same class works as expected when calling from Main.LoadAll() or Main.LoadById(id), but it's going into an endless loop when called from the API POST method using Post([FromBody]Main value).

Comment: I don't think it's related directly to what's been generated by CodeFluent, I suspect it's due to a cycle in serialization of instances. In memory they point to each other in a recursive manner if you follow the generated properties.

Comment: Well, that's the problem, you are right but... could you point to any solution?
I've done my homework 4 months googling and tracing but this problem is only on CodeFluent Entities generated code, not a clue of it at Entity Framework. The "In memory" pointing to each other is code generated from CodeFluent entities on which coders rely.